# Ethernet not getting braodcast packets

Tags: linux-device-driver, ethernet, dhcp, broadcasting, raw-ethernet

I'm working on 2.6.15 kernel running on a cisco IPTV. When the box is coming up, the DHCP client hangs up. The reason for this is that the DHCP client does not get fetch the broadcasted DHCP offer message.

When I read /proc/net/dev file, it shows that ethernet device (eth0) has not received any packet. I then ran tcpdump on the box and it also shows that no packet is been received on the ethernet interface.

Then I ran wireshark on the test PC (on which DHCP server is running), it shows that a DHCP offer message is broadcasted by the DHCP server.

This DHCP client and server are working fine with other boxes so there are less chances that these programs have any issues. There must be an issue in the ethernet drivers.

I'm really confused. How should I proceed to this problem. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can start by checking whether the DHCP client is sending out a discovery.

The DHCP handshake goes like this:
client discovery,
server offer,
client request,
server ack
(Wikipedia has the steps of DHCP)

The next thing you can check any DHCP related settings on the router.
Is the DHCP client on the same subnet/vlan as the server?  If not, would the router need a certain configuration to relay to/from the DHCP server subnet/vlan?